# Remove Select column in xslt web part

Tags: 2010, web-part, list-view, xslt, column

[image]

I have an xslt web part that I want to connect to another list.  When I connect it to another list I get the select column that I don't want to see.  How can I remove it?

More info
Originally I was using the data form web part for this list but it didn't include the option to add new items.  I like how the add new items popups up and is easy for the user.  As a workaround I tried inserting a link to do the same popup with the data form web part but it brought me to the full NewForm.aspx page which wasn't as nice as the popup that I've become used to.  If it's relevant this list only connects to 1 other list.

Answer (score 1):

The select column is the one that allows you to specify which item to send to the connected web part.

If you remove that column then you have no way of specifying that. And if you can't specify that then why then have the connection? If you remove the connection then the select column disapears.

If you really really want to keep the connection but hide the select column then you could probably include some jQuery on the page which will perform the following steps:

1. Find any div with attribute name = "Select"
2. Find out which number the parent th has within its parent tr. We call that X
3. Go to the tr's parent tbody
4. Set the child number X of all tr children of the tbody to display:none

Comment: In the data form web part it makes the values under platform links to specify the connection.  The data form web part is great but I would like the add new item feature that the xslt offers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the select column either - it's not the most intuitive for users at all, is it?

Here's what you could do:

Use an initially empty data view web part, then add your list as a data connection and then add the fields you want to display and use as a filter/connector to your other list/web part.

When you connect the two web parts you now get an option at the end to use the display field of the first list as a hyperlink to filter the second list.

If you do need the modal dialog for adding new items, then simply copy the link you get under a normal data view web part and add it to your new one. If you do this in code view you get the full JavaScript link (onclick) which will ensure that you get the modal dialog.

Hope this helps. Let me know if it doesn't; I'll provide more details.

Danny